# Console log throwing error for printing array of objects

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to console log the `myArry` in typescript but it shows an error in VS code editor.

Not sure what i'm doing wrong here.

`[ts] ';' expected.
(property) AppComponent.console: any`

```js
import {
  Component
} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  myArry = [
    {'name':'Arun','age':31},
    {'name':'Arun','age':30},
    {'name':'Arun','age':30}
  ];
  console.log(myArry);
}
```

Comment: where is this console.log placed?

Comment: inside export class AppComponent

Comment: well it needs to be in some method, in case you have just placed it outside "somewhere" in component.

Comment: Include the code for your component and remove all parts except for what is relevant to the question.

Comment: I've added the entire code

Comment: as said, put the console.log in a method, for example `ngOnInit() { console.log(myArry)}` I'd suggest you take a look at the Angular docs, specifically the TOH tutorial, you get the hang of the basics: https://angular.io/tutorial